# How do you code with three levels of quoting to represent code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Basically I have a respond_to block in my controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => "$('#test').html('<div class='colorize'>Test</div>');" }
end
```

I am also trying to add a css class `colorize` to the div block that will be rendered via js but using quotes there breaks the code.  How do I get this working with the class added in?

Comment: (Was the goal to show invalid JS syntax in the quote itself?)

Comment: you can escape your quotes using \

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here / what the problem is.

Comment: Sometimes, if something is hard, it's because you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save yourself a gigantic headache here, and don't put anything besides the simplest JS in your ruby handlers.

```
format.js { render :js => "colorizeTest()" }
```

And then on the page or via included script, declare a function:

```
var colorizeTest = function() {
  $('#test').html('<div class="colorize">Test</div>');
};
```

Don't put JS in your Ruby.

---

Or you could use a real view template:

```
# controller code
@some_id = 'test'

# JS format Handler
format.js

# views/whatever.ejs.js
$('#<%= @some_id %>').html('<div class="colorize">Test</div>');
```

---

Or do both! In this example, this much abstraction is silly, but as soon as this JS starts doing anything even slightly complex, this will be the best way.  Pass more data, less code, via generated js responses. Real complex js logic should *always* be included statically on the page.

```
# controller code
@some_id = 'test'

# JS format Handler
format.js

// js funciton on page
var colorizeTest = function(id) {
  $('#' + id).html('<div class="colorize">Test</div>');
};

# views/whatever.ejs.js
colorizeTest(<%= @some_id %>);
```

---

Lastly, I might also argue the true "best" way is only render JSON from the server, and you have statically included JS that handles fetching that via AJAX, and handling what to do with the page based on that data.  This way you never "generate" executable javascript server side at all, which is very clean.

```
// js file somewhere
var colorizeTest = function(id) {
  $('#' + id).html('<div class="colorize">Test</div>');
};

var doStuff = function() {
  $.getJSON("/whatever.json", function(data) {
    colorizeTest(data.id);
  });
};

# rails controller
render :json => { :id => 'test' }
```

See how now you dont have any JS in your ruby at all? Or any ruby in your JS for that matter? Just sending data between server and client. Man that's nice. Just how I like it.

Comment: +1 to this. Generating complex chunks of source code is almost never a good idea. If you're reusing a nontrivial chunk of JS, it should be a function in your JS files.

Comment: In your second piece of code, you have two nested `'`s, when one should be a `"`.

Comment: The message in the javascript respond block is just a short one line message so would that be ok to put js in the ruby controller action?

Comment: @persistence It'll work that way, sure. It depends on how clean you want it to be, and how complex the real logic is. (Your example isn't real logic). Anything beyond a single function being called with an argument or two, should be refactored out for sure. But in an ideal world, you would _never_ have JS in your ruby. How ideal do you want to be?

Answer (score 4):

Backslashes?

```
" ' \" \' \\\" \\\' \\\\\" \\\\\' ... \\\\\' \\\\\" \\\' \\\" \' \" ' "
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to backslashes,

```
%Q[$('#tes­t').html("­<div class­='colorize­'>Test</div>");]
```

However, this is Ruby, not JavaScript. Within pure JavaScript, `%q`/`%Q` is not available.

EDIT: Also, Alex Wayne has the best advice of all.